# fiveYearAverageReturn not working for yfinance in Python

Tags: python, yfinance

The "fiveYearAverageReturn" for stocks is not working correctly on Python, it always displays "None" no matter what stock you pick.

```
import yfinance as yf 
stock_info = yf.Ticker("MSFT").info
average_return = stock_info["fiveYearAverageReturn"]

print("MSFT's 5 year average return: " , average_return)
```

This returns

```
MSFT's 5 year average return: None
```

But this should return something around 193%. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: It may not be something that is in all tickers as it shows none when you get other tickers.

Comment: The fields ytdReturn/threeYearAverageReturn/fiveYearAverageReturn are returned from yfinance but I believe they are deprecated and will always return None.